# Can quantifiers be used on variables bound on the left side of the pipe in Tuple Relational Calculus?

Tags: relational-algebra, tuple-relational-calculus

Our professor has solved an example for us. They taught us it's incorrect to use a quantifier (`exists` or `forall`) with a variable that's already bound on the left side of the pipe (`|`, meaning "such that"). They've done that in their example solution. Can quantifiers be used on variables bound on the left side of the pipe in TRC?

Their question and solution:

> R consists of three columns (a, b, and, c), and a is the primary key. Similarly, S consists of three columns (d, e, and, f), and d is the primary key.
>
> Write the TRC query that is equivalent to the following Relational Algebra query: `R ⟕ S` [natural left outer join].
>
> ```
> {r.*, s.* |
>     // There are two tuples to join
>     (r ∈ R ∧ s ∈ S ∧ r.a = s.d) ∨
>     // or there is a tuple in R without a tuple in S
>     (r ∈ R ∧ NOT (∃s ∈ S) (r.a = s.d))
>     }
> ```

Is this correct?

I would've answered:

```
{r.*, s.* | 
    // There are two tuples to join
    (r ∈ R ∧ s ∈ S ∧ r.a = s.d) ∨
    // or there is a tuple in R without a tuple in S
    (r ∈ R ∧ (NOT (s ∈ S)) ∧ (r.a = s.d))
}
```

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. PS It's not incorrect to reuse a variable name. But the quantified variable isn't any outer variable by that name. What **exactly** were you told? And the textbook's definition of your TRC notation is what? PS The 1st comment unhelpfully mixes algebra & TRC. The 2nd is not defining left outer join. Your TRC isn't right either. You've been mislead by the bad 2nd comment. But the comment isn't actually clear, what do you claim it means? And again: Quote an authoritative definition.--Justify your work.

Comment: Neither query can be correct because left outer join output includes tuples where columns have introduced nulls but the comprehensions don't ever say member rows have columns that are null. [Re relational querying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097)  [Difference between Relational Algebra and Relational calculus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841232/3404097) [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: "What exactly were you told?" We were told "Only free tuple variables in a tuple relational calculus expression should be those that appear to the left of the bar." In this context I believe he means free vs. bound variables. On the previous slide he explains bound as quantified with exists or forall on the right side of the bar.

Comment: I am reading and learning from the questions you linked, it might take me some time to fully understand them. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS How do you think the code violates the comment quote? It doesn't. r & s are free in the RHS expression. s is also bound in a subexpression of it--but so what? (Rhetorical.) Your comment quote does not say what you paraphrase in the post. So you have a further misunderstanding. PS Did you really mean left join? You used the symbol, I added the words. But since neither query gives left join, maybe you used the wrong symbol? But neither query is any other common operator/symbol either.

Comment: The variables on the LHS of a query are not "bound" in the sense used in the definition of a query wff. Although they would be bound in a formal predicate logic version of what a query means and/or what using a query means. So we might say they are implicitly (predicate logically) bound. But what is your justification for calling them bound? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: I commented re "1" question because your query isn't needed to ask the explicit question & very often people include content that is not a literal question but seem to mean to ask about it too. Also, if considered part of the question (unfortunately without it having been clearly made so) it adds further premises & if wrong then an answer becomes, that premise is wrong & you don't get your true question answered. PS Both queries allow (per `∨`) rows with a s subrow with some columns with arbitrary values. That's "unsafe" hence illegal.) PS 1st query 2nd disjunct needs `and s.* are NULL`.

Comment: `R ⟕ S` is natural left join. The 1st query after my fix above is still not that. It's like SQL `R left join S on R.a = S.d` which in your RA might be like `R ⟕ {a = d} S` with `⟕ {⋅}` maybe called left theta join. Constraints don't change the result of relational or SQL expressions. They imply some expressions return the same as others that you could have written anyway. They restrict what inputs can arise & consequently restrict the corresponding outputs. The PKs of R & S do not cause `R ⟕ S` to return anything different; here, not `R ⟕ {a = d} S`. That quoted Q&A is really screwed up.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing how your professor reacted re my comments re their query.